# Where in the World

Tags: word

**Clue 1**

> viB .G yo_

**Clue 2**

> What do we have in common:
>   Sandwich, Island, Liberty

**Clue 3**

> " _ L _ _ S "

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

Clue #1: viB .G yo_

> This is "**R**oy G. Biv" backwards, so **R**.

Clue #2: What do we have in common:
Sandwich, Island, Liberty

> Sandw**i**ch, **I**sland, L**i**berty, the letter **I** is the only one these words share in common.

Based on these first two clues, I wonder if clue #3 indicates some specific location in

> Rhode Island (state with code **RI**)

Stuck on clue #3, am wondering if

> The double quotes are significant in some way, or if the concepts like rainbow and the words from clue #2 are supposed to point us in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, the double quotes have no bearing

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer
This might be:

> ELLIS ISLAND

Clue 2:

> It's like a **Sandwich Island** between New York and New Jersey and called New York Harbor. This was made part of the Statue of **Liberty** National Monument.

Clue 3:

> E **L** L I **S**

finally

> Still to find Clue 1.

Comment: Good try, but didnt factor in clue 1 as you said.